# How to Limit UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to Limit `UICollectionViewCell` to 10 or 20? If `UICollectionViewCell` load so many cell from API.

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.items.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    eventisi* list = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *iconEvent = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:list.EVENT_IMAGE];
    [iconEvent setImageWithURL:url usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    iconEvent.clipsToBounds = YES;
    // Configure the cell
    UILabel *judul = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    judul.text = list.EVENT_NAME;
    judul.numberOfLines =2;
    judul.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    judul.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can return fewer items in `numberOfItemsInSection`.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the elements in `self.items`. The amount of cells displayed by a UICollectionView depends on the `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` method, which entirely depends on the number of elements in `self.items`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a maximum of 20 `UICollectionViewCell`s (depending on the number of items in `self.items` ) :

```
-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(self.items.count >= 20) {
        return 20;
    } 

    return self.items.count;
}
```